# Loopback, Angular Yeoman

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, yeoman, loopbackjs

I try to setup a project server with `loopback` as a back-end and I want to use `Angular` for the fronted. I use `Yeoman` to scaffold the angular project in the client folder of my loopback project. Works fine and I can call `index.html`.

But when I load the page, I get the `error` that the **variable angular can't be found**. Obviously its because angular is not loaded, or ? So I checked the `index.html` and right it is not loaded.

Should Yeoman not take of this ? I checked bower components(in the client folder) and angular is installed.

How can I fix this error without manually adding the path to the **index.html** file, or am I wrong at Yeoman does not take of it and **I HAVE** to set the path manually?

Comment: What Yeoman generator are you using?

Comment: This one: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Comment: using generator-angular, you have to run 'grunt build, it should automatic import the angular lib inside the comment ' <!-- bower:js -->' in the index.html

Comment: Thank you so much Rafael! I totally did not know that!